# django-selectable: no drop down

Tags: django, autocomplete

I'm trying to use django-selectable http://django-selectable.readthedocs.org/en/version-0.6.2/quick-start.html

I have setup everything from what I can tell correctly (see blow). In FireBug the request is being made and valid JSON is being returned. Everything is working, however no results display. I have included the CSS.

Any reason why I don't see the drop down?

FF has this error:

```
TypeError: this.menu is undefined
[Break On This Error]   

if ( this.menu.element.is( ":visible" ) ) {
```

**models.py**

```
class Event(models.Model):
    event_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=80,blank=False)
    date = models.DateField()
    start = models.TimeField()
    end = models.TimeField()

    category = models.ForeignKey(Category)
    city = models.ForeignKey(City)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

**lookup.py**

```
from selectable.base import ModelLookup
from selectable.registry import registry

from events.models import Event


class EventLookup(ModelLookup):
    model = Event
    search_field = 'city__icontains'
    filters = {'active': True, }

    def get_item_value(self, item):
        # Display for currently selected item
        return item.name

    def get_item_label(self, item):

        return u"%s (%s)" % (item.name)

registry.register(EventLookup)
```

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from django.forms import ModelForm
from events.models import Event
import selectable.forms as selectable
from events.lookups import EventLookup


class EventForm(ModelForm):
    autocomplete = forms.CharField(
        label='Type the name of a fruit (AutoCompleteWidget)',
        widget=selectable.AutoCompleteWidget(EventLookup),
        required=False,
    )

    class Meta:
        model = Event
```

**urls.py**

```
(r'^selectable/', include('selectable.urls')),
```

**template.html**

```
  **the following is loaded in correctly...**
    jquery-1.9.0.js
    jquery-ui-1.10.0.custom.min.css
    jquery.ui.core.js
    jquery.ui.widget.js
    jquery.ui.datepicker.js
    jquery.ui.autocomplete.js


     {{ form.media.css }} 
     {{ form.media.js }} 
     {{ form }}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That looks correct, I think either:

1) you're not including the js files in the correct order

or

2) you're not loading them correctly.

Add below to your head and remove your links, see if it works...

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/
1.8.13/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/
jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
{{ form.media.js }}
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/
jqueryui/1.8.13/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
{{ form.media.css }}
```

Comment: try your code it seemed to work. I think it was the jQuery version also. thanks